# I have a problem with running a python script as a systemd service

Tags: python, systemd, python-daemon

I have a reminder app and i want to run it as a service. I created a service file called 'reminder_py.service' under '/lib/systemd/system'. commands inside 'reminder_py.service':

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Username=hrx
Groupname=hrx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/hrx/reminder/reminder.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I tried to start it with the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable reminder_py.service
sudo systemctl start reminder_py.service
```

But the `sudo systemctl status reminder_py.service` command says:

```
hrx@X230:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status reminder_py.service
● reminder_py.service - Dummy Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/reminder_py.service; enabled; vendor p>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-08-15 23:59:06 +03; 2min>
    Process: 13952 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/hrx/reminder/reminder.py (c>
   Main PID: 13952 (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 15 23:59:06 X230 systemd[1]: Started Dummy Service.
Aug 15 23:59:06 X230 systemd[1]: reminder_py.service: Main process exited, code>
Aug 15 23:59:06 X230 systemd[1]: reminder_py.service: Failed with result 'exit->
```

How can I solve this problem?

Maybe the following can help:

```
hrx@X230:/lib/systemd/system$ users
hrx

hrx@X230:/lib/systemd/system$ groups
hrx adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare


hrx@X230:/lib/systemd/system$ ls -al | grep reminder_py.service 
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   256 Aug 15 23:55 reminder_py.service
```

And I found a comment from another site that could help me. But I don't quite understand what he's saying.

> A fine and simple to follow tutorial. I would add a couple of caveats – with the .service file as written the python script will be run as root and this may have unintended consequences. Also the environment will be different from that for a normal user. To fix add the lines `User=username` and `Group=groupname` before the `ExecStart` line. To add environment variables expected by the script add the line `Environment=”variable_name=variable_value”` before the `ExecStart` line.

Comment: what happens when you manually launch the script?

Comment: Works well when i manually launch. @Marat

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what "works well" is? does it print something as expected and stops, does it serve a website, or starts a bunch of other processes and remains a zombie?

Comment: It checks a text file to notify tasks in the text file when the time comes. here is the repository:  https://github.com/sifirib/reminder/blob/master/reminder/reminder.py

@Marat

Comment: if there are no tasks, the program will exit immediately, calling `sys.exit` with invalid status. This is exactly the problem the question

Comment: I am having the same problem when the text file is full of tasks for it.@Marat

Comment: well, it is pretty hard to tell what's going on without access to the machine. Some logging might help

Comment: If you want access my machine, I will let you to help me.

Comment: sorry, I will not

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing contents of the file with:

```
[Unit]
Description=Reminder App
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/hrx/anaconda3/bin/python /home/hrx/Desktop/reminder/reminder.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To learn the path of python run this command:

```
type -a python
```